# List all user-defined variables in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

In python I can use [dir()](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/dir.html) and in racket (5.2) I can do

```
 (require xrepl)
 ,apropos
```

to get a list of all defined variables.  What portable method exists to do the same in all schemes?  That done, how do I filter out all the system and module variables? The full list of variables is rather daunting in racket.

Comment: What do you mean by "system and module variables"?  Which ones *do* you want to see?

Comment: There is no way to do that in all schemes.

Comment: I only want to see user variables, not stuff defined by other modules or by the system.

Comment: There are no distinction between "user" variables and "system" variables. If your code begins with #lang then you are writting a module. The system libraries are also defined as modules. There is no difference. But I am confused. You said you wanted the same as Python dir(). From the manual: "The built-in function dir() is used to find out which names a module defines." So your question was about variables in module?

Comment: I guess "user" isn't very clear. Often I leave my REPL open for long stretches.  I may have left something half done and I don't remember the names of variables that I have used.  I'd like to see a list of them.  Python dir() with no parameters will give me a list of all vars in the local namespace, including imports and system variables (I could also use locals()). ,apropos seems to do the same, but the list is HUGE and xrepl isn't always available.  There should be some way to get a list of names in the local namespace, then perhaps subtract out the list that you gave in your answer below.

Answer (score 6):

To get the names exported by a specific module in Racket use [module->exports](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=module#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._module-~3eexports%29%29). For other implementations, you need to look it up in the documentation.

```
> (module->exports 'racket/list)
'((0
   (add-between ()) (append* ())    (append-map ())
   (argmax ())      (argmin ())     (cons? ()) (count ())
   (drop ())        (drop-right ()) (eighth ()) (empty ())
   (empty? ())      (fifth ())      (filter-map ())
   (filter-not ())  (first ())      (flatten ())
   (fourth ())      (last ())       (last-pair ())
   (make-list ())   (ninth ())      (partition ())
   (range ())       (rest ())       (second ())
   (seventh ())     (shuffle ())    (sixth ())
   (split-at ())    (split-at-right ()) (take ())
   (take-right ())  (tenth ()) (third ())))
'((0 (remove-duplicates ())))
```

Comment: That's interesting and useful, but it's the inverse of what I want.  I'd like to filter all of those out and see what is left.

Comment: In the Racket REPL, you can probably use *namespace-mapped-symbols* to get a list of all the bindings currently accessible, and then subtract the bindings from the language.  Something like *(set->list (set-subtract (list->set (namespace-mapped-symbols)) (list->set (namespace-mapped-symbols (module->namespace 'racket)))))*.

Comment: @dyoo Your code comes as close as I can reasonably get (ie. works in different environments like xrepl and geiser). If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, here's how to do it in [guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) (v. >= 2.0):

```
scheme@(guile-user)> ,binding
%module-public-interface #<variable 9e55e98 value: #<interface (guile-user) 9df6678>>

scheme@(guile-user)> (define foo 'bar)

scheme@(guile-user)> ,binding
foo                     #<variable a06fe28 value: bar>
%module-public-interface #<variable 9e55e98 value: #<interface (guile-user) 9df6678>>
```

You can change contexts to get the bindings exported by certain modules:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (use-modules (srfi srfi-1))
scheme@(guile-user)> ,module (srfi srfi-1)
scheme@(srfi srfi-1)> ,binding
reduce-right            #<variable 9ead2d0 value: #<procedure reduce-right (f ridentity lst)>>
delete                  #<variable 9eb7aa8 value: #<procedure delete (_ _ #:optional _)>>
lset-xor!               #<variable 9eb7c90 value: #<procedure lset-xor! (= . rest)>>
take!                   #<variable 9ead640 value: #<procedure take! (lst i)>>
...
```

Comment: Nice! Alas, xrepl doesn't have ,binding